# where to download com.intellij.lang.javascript.psi

Tags: plugins, intellij-idea, eslint

i am reading the source code of [eslint-plugin](https://github.com/idok/eslint-plugin)

but when i build it, i get a error "com.intellij.lang.javascript.psi not exist".

the version of  intellij idea i use  is 14.1.3 ulimate.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a *IntelliJ Platform Plugin SDK* and use that for the project. You can create this in *Project Structure > Platform Settings > SDKs* (Make sure you have the *Plugin DevKit* plugin enabled).

Comment: i has set the IntelliJ Platform Plugin SDK

IntelliJ Platform Plugin SDK home path : E:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.3
but i don't find com.intellij.lang.javascript.psi in E:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.3

Answer (score 0):

Where intellij is installed eg C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 17.xxx

navigate to

lib/plugins/JavaScriptLanguage/lib

the jar is in there.